# Efficiently Reshaping/Reordering Numpy Array to Properly Ordered Tiles (Image)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I would like to be able to somehow reorder a numpy array for efficient processing of tiles.

what I got:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).repeat(2,0).repeat(2,1)
>>> A  # image like array
array([[[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]]])

>>> A.reshape(2,2,4)
array([[[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]]])
```

what I want: **How to get X:**

```
>>> X
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Is this possible without a slow python loop?

Bonus: Conversion back from X to A

Bago pointed out a similar question I had missed: [Creating a 4D view on 2D array to divide it into cells of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006232/creating-a-4d-view-on-2d-array-to-divide-it-into-cells-of-fixed-size)

---

Why all the trouble? To be able to do something like:

```
>>> X[X.sum(2)>12] -= 1
>>> X
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

**Edit: Solution:**

```
# MIT - License

import numpy as np

def tile_reorder(A, t):
    """reshape and transpose quadratic array for easy access to quadratic tiles of size t"""
    l = A.shape[0] / t
    X = A.reshape((l, t, l, t))
    X = X.transpose([0, 2, 1, 3])
    return X

def tile_reorder_reverse(X):
    l = X.shape[0] * X.shape[2]
    A = X.transpose([0, 2, 1, 3])
    A = A.reshape((l, l))
    return A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]).repeat(4,0).repeat(4,1)

    print "A:\n", A, "\n\n"

    print "A_tiled:\n", tile_reorder(A,4), "\n\n"

    print "A_tiled_reversed:\n", tile_reorder_reverse(tile_reorder(A,4)), "\n\n"

    X = tile_reorder(A,4)
    X[X.sum((2)).sum(2)>63,:,:] += 10
    B = tile_reorder_reverse(X)

    print "B_processed:\n", B, "\n\n"
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Which step of the code that you listed is not working for you. NumPy does have logical type indexing, some something like `X[X.sum(2)>12]` should work. The problem is that you need to figure out which dimension of your array you want to index on. It looks like you want to say `X[:,:,X.sum(2)>12] -= 1`, because the indices you want to mess with are only those that have a third index along which the sum exceeds 12, and the first and second indices could be anything.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, the conversion back isn't possible. You are losing information, you're mapping the original set to a smaller subset.

Comment: Hope I made things a little clearer. The indexing is not what is causing me the pita.

Comment: I don't understand your comment: there is an indexing error in your post that's corrected in my answer below. I made an edit that includes use of `hstack` and `vstack` which should get you back from the 3-D array to the correct 2-D tiling. You'll have to note in the code where the right locations are to generalize the dimensions of your array, for example if you have more than a 2x2 tiling.

Comment: Made some changes to hopefully make the question more clear.

Comment: @EMS: The indexing works fine for me like that (not part of the question). If there is an error it still does what I expect it to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like:

```
>>> X = A.reshape(2,2,2,2)
>>> X = X.transpose([0,2,1,3])
>>> X = X.reshape((2,2,-1))
>>> X
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
>>> B = X.reshape((2,2,2,2))
>>> B = B.transpose([0,2,1,3])
>>> B = B.reshape((2,2,-1))
>>> B
array([[[1, 1, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: This has the problem that it doesn't generalize to an `MxN` tiling where the tile dimensions should still be 2x2 but there the larger pattern of tiles is more than 2x2. It would be great to see this concise code modified to handle arbitrary `KxP` tilings, each of which is `MxN`.

Comment: There is no reason it doesn't generalize, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006232/creating-a-4d-view-on-2d-array-to-divide-it-into-cells-of-fixed-size

Comment: Try running your code on the example I appended to the end of my answer. Your code gives an error; I tried it. If it "works" by changing the numbers in your calls to reshape and transpose, then my comment above still applies -- I think your approach is only valuable if you demonstrate how to feed tile parameters to the reshape and transpose code and get this to work on a generically shaped tiled array where the tiles are also generically shaped.

Comment: Feel free to update the answer with that information (it's not too hard). If you can't figure it out, ask a new question and I might answer it.

Comment: That's OK. I already have made the generalization to your method. I just felt you might want to provide that answer. If you do not, that is OK. I see it as an incomplete answer, but that is just my opinion, and it doesn't detract from the benefit your approach provides in terms of concise code that relies on optimized NumPy built-ins.

Comment: this looks good. will try to undestand and generalize it tomorrow morning (and ems' post)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just looking at the wrong slice of your array. The following should do what you want.

```
>>> X[(X.sum(2)>12),:] -= 1
>>> X
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

To get back to the original ordering is a little more complicated. I'm sure you can modify the code below into a function called `get_back()` or something so you don't have to reuse this all the time.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.asarray([[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]],[[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]])
print X

# Make the change to the array
# Note that I make the change to +=1 so we can indeed see that
# the reshaping worked by looking for the 5's.
X[(X.sum(2)>12),:] += 1

(M,N,P) = X.shape;      # Number of tiles is MxN
orig_i = 2; orig_j = 2; # (Original rows/cols in a tile).
orig = (orig_i, orig_j) # Define as a tuple for convenience.
hstacks = []
for ii in range(M):
    hstacks.append(X[ii,0,:].reshape(orig))
    for jj in range(1,N):
        hstacks[-1] = np.hstack(( hstacks[-1], X[ii,jj,:].reshape(orig) ))

orig_array = hstacks[0]
for kk in range(1,len(hstacks)):
    orig_array = np.vstack(( orig_array, hstacks[kk] ))

# Print to confirm that it worked.
print orig_array
```

I get the following:

```
>>> [[[1 1 1 1]
      [2 2 2 2]]

     [[3 3 3 3]
      [4 4 4 4]]]

>>> [[1 1 2 2]
     [1 1 2 2]
     [3 3 5 5]
     [3 3 5 5]]
```

And to test, I tried it with a larger pattern of tiles as well and it gives the correct result. Note that I use a function `get_back()` to encapsulate the above code, and I just hard-coded in the tiling dimension parameters into the function. Really they should be input parameters.

```
>>> X = np.asarray([[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]],
                    [[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]])
>>> X
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6, 6]]])

>>> get_back(X)
array([[1 1 2 2 3 3]
       [1 1 2 2 3 3]
       [4 4 5 5 6 6]
       [4 4 5 5 6 6]])
```

Comment: This way would work, too, but bago's solution while not yet generalized is more elegant should be faster.